# file.getDownloadUrl() not working for Google Add-on Apps Script

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-drive-api

I am creating a google add-on for Google Drive. I am using the [DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app)  class to access and handle files. I would like to be able to generate a link for downloading a file. Eventually, I want to send this download link to a server for further file processing.

DriveApp's [file](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file) class appears to have a perfect method for this purpose, `file.getDownloadUrl()`, which "*Gets the URL that can be used to download the file.*"

Unfortunately, I am seeing some strange behavior and I am not sure if I am using the method correctly.

First, the method returns null when called on Google's filetypes, e.g. `application/vnd.google-apps.document`or `application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet`. It makes sense that we may need to set some kind of parameter for what filetype we'd like to export to, but that does not appear to be an option for `getDownloadUrl()`.

Second, when `getDownloadUrl()` does return a url, access to the url is severely restricted. Unless I am on Chrome and signed into the file owner's G Suite account, I cannot access the file. Signing into the owner account, but browsing on Firefox also returns a 403 error.

I have a flask server running on a set of [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk) credentials. Is there a way to authorize those credentials to access this download link?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Files that have the [Google MIME type](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/mime-types) cannot be downloaded directly, and `file.getDownloadUrl()` returns null.

For example, a Spreadsheet.

Before downloading manually, you can see that the file is converted to `.xlsx`. So to download it, you need to convert the file into something.

```js
    // --- Apps Script ---
    let new_file = Drive.Files.insert({ //DriveApi
        title: file.getName(), //name
        parents: [{
          id: file.getParents().next().getId() //folder
        }],
        mimeType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" //new mimeType
      },
      file.getBlob()
    );

    console.log(new_file.getDownloadUrl())
```

However, to download a file from this link, you need to be logged in to Google and have access to the file in Drive.

Otherwise, you can get a [blob](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob.html) of a file and convert it to a file in another place, for example, on your server.

```js
    // --- Apps Script ---
    let blob = file.getBlob()
    let blob_type = blob.getContentType() // for some reason, this is a application/pdf, so it will download as .pdf
    let blob_string = blob.getDataAsString() // data of this blob as a String with UTF-8 encoding
```

```js
    // --- JS ---
    // convert to js blob
    let js_blob = new Blob([blob_string], {
      type: blob_type
    });
    // and download
    let a = document.createElement("a")
    document.body.appendChild(a)
    a.style = "display: none"
    let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(js_blob)
    a.href = url
    a.download = "fileName.pdf" //file name and extension
    a.click()
    a.remove()
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url)
```